# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre igual (adverbio) e igualmente?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, sinónimos, adverbios

Según la RAE, tanto *igual* como *igualmente* puede ser adverbio. ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los dos (con ese significado)? ¿Son sinónimos exactos, o se usan de maneras distintas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si consultamos el DRAE, podemos ver que si bien ambos pueden utilizarse como adverbios (*igual* también puede ser adjetivo) el significado es distinto y por tanto su uso:

La definición de [***igualmente***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KwnRYR3) es:

> 1. adv. m. Con igualdad.
> 2. adv. m. También, asimismo.

Mientras que [***igual***](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=tKOfxXxw7DXX20BRavrG) (DLE 2001) es:

> 1. adv. m. De la misma manera.
> 2. adv. m. Arg. y Ur. A pesar de todo, no obstante. Ejemplo: *Aunque mañana llueva, igual salimos de paseo.*
> 3. adv. duda coloq. quizá. Ejemplo: *Igual mañana nieva.*

Podemos decir *Igual mañana nieva* pero **no** podemos decir *Igualmente mañana nieva*.

Comment: Se refiere a cuando igual funciona como adverbio.

Comment: Las definiciones que he incluido se refieren al uso como adverbio. ¿no?

Comment: Es curioso que esta respuesta tenga un voto negativo cuando, en mi opinión, es la única correcta que se ha escrito hasta ahora.

Answer (score 3):

Igual es un adjetivo y algunas veces puede ser usado como adverbio.

**Como Adjetivo:**

'Igual' puede ser usado cuando queremos expresar 'equivalencia' (En Inglés '*equal*').

Ejemplo:

> Las dos monedas son iguales.

**Como Adverbio:**

'Igual' puede ser usado cuando queremos expresar 'De la misma manera'.

Ejemplo:

> Aunque no es hermoso, igual lo adoro.

'Igualmente' es siempre usado como un adverbio.
'Igualmente' puede ser usado cuando queremos expresar 'con igualdad' (En ingles equally)
Ejemplo:

> El perro ladra en la madrugada igualmente que en la noche

Comment: Sí, pero, ¿hay alguna diferencia en entre "igualmente" e "igual" cuando este último funciona como adverbio?

Comment: Bienvenida a Spanish.SE, esperamos verte seguido por aquí.

Answer (score 2):

Que yo sepa, **no hay diferencia** en su uso como adverbios.

Lo mismo ocurre con *sólo* (o *solo*) y *solamente*.

Comment: Sólo (acentuado, advervio y sinónimo de solamente) y solo (sin acentuar, no adverbio y no es sinónimo de solamente.) no son lo mismo.

Comment: Aunque you escribo el adverbio como «sólo», tengo entendido que se acepta escribirlo sin tilde, «solo», y que de hecho es la tendencia¹. Ya sé que «solo», además, puede actuar como adjetivo. Notas: ¹ http://www.rae.es/drae/?type=3&val=solo&val_aux=&origen=RAE

Answer (score -1):

Igual (funcionando como adverbio) y el adverbio igualmente. Tienen exactamente el mismo significado. Como nota curiosa, cuando se utiliza igual como adverbio siempre se escribe obligatoriamente que detrás. Ver: http://lenguajealdia.blogspot.com.es/2008/02/igual-adjetivo-y-adverbio.html

Comment: Me temo que has entendido mal lo que pone en esta página. No es obligatorio usar *que* detrás de *igual* cuando funciona como adverbio; lo que dice es que, si hay un segundo término, solo puede introducirse con *que*, a diferencia de lo que ocurre cuando funciona como adjetivo (lo explica más arriba en el enlace). Pero se puede usar *igual* como adverbio sin que haya segundo término.